# less with color and locale

Tags: colors, less, locale

Using cygwin I've a problem in less: I can't see colors (for example using grep --color) and I can't set the locale I'm using (LC_ALL=C).

I type this command:

```
echo òùàòùàòà | grep --color àò | sort | less -R
```

and the result is:

```
<C3><B2><C3><B9><C3><A0><C3><B2><C3><B9><C3><A0><C3><B2><C3><A0>
```

**EDIT:**
This work:

```
ls --color=yes | less -R
```

less --version  -> 444

**EDIT2:**
solved the problem of colors using the option `--color=always`, but not solved the problem of locale.
[image: Less with colors but strange output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this on Cygwin at the moment, but both of these solutions worked for me on Fedora.

```
echo òùàòùàòà | grep --color=always àò | sort | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 less -R

echo òùàòùàòà | grep --color=always àò | sort | LESSCHARSET=utf-8 less -R
```

**UPDATE:**

Just verified that the above work using Cygwin 1.7.9 on Windows XP SP3.